# PHP, mysql & two databases - updating certain rows in 2nd database table from table in 1st db with different schema

Tags: php, mysql, database

I've got the logic working (when entered directly in phpmyadmin) but not sure how it can be converted to php. I would be most grateful for assistance with this translation to php statements.

The working mysql logic is listed between the hash signs (in that I've been figuring out the other php statements required). To clarify the logic/process, I have one table in db2 holding a set of 'averages' for certain id's. I'm wanting to move these averages over to the equivalent 'average' field in a db1 table. The matching has to be done via the id field which is common to both tables, though db2 does not have an entry for every id listed in db1.

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser1 = 'dbuser1';
$dbpass1 = 'dbpass1';
$dbuser2 = 'dbuser2';
$dbpass2 = 'dbpass2';
$conn1 = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser1, $dbpass1);
$conn2 = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser2, $dbpass2, true);
if(! $conn1 || ! $conn2 )
{
  die('Could not connect to db1 or db2: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db('db1', $conn1 );
mysql_select_db('db2', $conn2);

#####
update db1.gfields, db2.averages
set db1.gfields.ratingavg = db2.averages.average
where db1.gfields.id = db2.averages.id;

this is an after-fix edit to show the code that solved the issue (initially provided below by KyleMassacre & updated slightly. Works with two connections, didn't try with one.)

$q = mysql_query("select * from averages", $conn2);

while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($q)) {
$u = mysql_query("update gfields set ratingavg = " . $r["average"] . " where id = " . $r["id"], $conn1);

#####

mysql_close($conn1);
mysql_close($conn2);
?>
```

Comment: `mysql_*` is deprecated, and has been for a while now.  Look into mysqli or PDO.

Comment: Aside from that, you're probably going to have a hell of a time trying to get two distinct connections to cooperate on one query.  You'd do better to use one connection or the other, and make sure that connection's user has access to the other database.

Comment: I've gathered that, however the scripts I'm working on are based on the depreciated php versions plus I'm not sure it really impacts the core aspect of my question (i.e. how to express the mysql logic between the tags in php). Am thinking that opening a connection to the first db and storing the results in an array--then accessing the second db/updating it, might be the way to go, though I am unclear as to how to do this in php.

Comment: *I've got the logic working (when entered directly in phpmyadmin)* What database (db1 or db2) you were connected to when successfuly executed this update query in phpmyadmin?

Comment: yes as mentioned in above comment (cHao) you take only one connection..eg... db1  and acess the tables of other db by db2.table.column..

Comment: peterm, I was using plesk 11.5 which now has the ability to connect to multiple dbs and run a query on them.

Comment: You couldn't possibly execute one query using 2 connections even with plesk. That was the whole point of asking you this question. Use the connection to one db from which you have enough rights to access another and execute your query.

Comment: Hi peterm, I hear what your saying & it might be that even though both db's have different usernames and passwords that access can be gained from one to the other directly, but the two connection script is working. Thank you for responding to my question it is appreciated very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me try this out and sorry for any errors since I'm on my phone

```
$q = mysql_query("select * from db1.gfields", $conn2);

while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($q))
    $u = mysql_query("update averages set average = " . $r["ratingavg"] . " where id = " . $r["id"], $conn2);

mysql_close($conn2);
```

also mysql_* is pretty much deprecated so maybe at some point in time look into mysqli or possibly PDO

Updated.  This is assuming your user has sufficient privs.

Comment: do it with one connection only

Comment: Updated post. I swapped it to a single connection using the connection to the destination db

Comment: Way to go Kyle! Works a treat. Had to update some of the fields slightly, as per the edit I've placed in original question. Works fine with two connections. Again, many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You should make one connection to the server with an account that has access to both databases, and then use the query you already had:

```
update
  database1.table as t1,
  database2.othertable as t2
set
  t1.name = t2.name
where
  t1.id = t2.id
```

If you execute the query this way, it will only update the records where the ID matches, and it will skip all the other records. It's not possible to use two separate database connections and sync the data that way.